# Weird behavior in str count with Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
>>> sample_dataframe
        P
0  107.35
1   99.35
2   75.85
3   92.34
```

When I try the following, the output is as follows:

```
>>> sample_dataframe[sample_dataframe['P'].astype(str).str.count('.') == 1]

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [P]
Index: []
```

Whereas using the regex escaped character, the following occurs:

```
>>> sample_dataframe[sample_dataframe['P'].astype(str).str.count('\.') == 1]

        P
0  107.35
1   99.35
2   75.85
3   92.34
```

The following further reinforces this:

```
>>> sample_dataframe['P'].astype(str).str.count('.')

0    6
1    5
2    5
3    5
Name: P, dtype: int64
```

vs.

```
sample_dataframe['P'].astype(str).str.count('\.')

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
Name: P, dtype: int64
```

Thus, the `.` expression is actually counting all characters as the regex wildcard character, minus newline characters, hence the counts 6, 5, 5, 5 vs. the escaped `\.`, which only counts the occurrence of the actual character `.`.

However, the regular function called from the string itself seems to be acting differently and doesn't need a regex escape of the '.':

```
>>> '105.35'.count('.')
1

>>> '105.35'.count('\.')
0
```

EDIT: Based on some of the answers, I will try to clarify the class function calls below (whereas right above is the instantiated object's method call):

```
>>> str.count('105.35', '.')
1

>>> str.count('105.35', '\.')
0
```

I am not sure if Pandas-related methods using CPython under the hood (due to NumPy operations) implements this as a Regex (including for df.apply), or if this is related to the difference in the `str` class function `count` (i.e. `str.count()`) vs. the `str` class method of the instantiated object (in the above example `'105.35'`) `count` (i.e. `'105.35'.count()`). Is the difference between class vs. object function/method the underlying cause (and how they are implemented), or is this caused by how DataFrames are implemented via NumPy?

I would really like some more information on this to truly understand how this works

Comment: To me it looks like you discovered how it works.

Comment: Because [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html#pandas-series-str-count) takes a regex pattern as first arg wheres [`string.count`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) takes a substring.

Comment: @Aryerez I would like to know what the underlying cause of this is. Whether a) this is how Pandas implemented it, or the distinction is due to class function vs. object method distinctions for the str class.

Comment: @HenryYik I am not calling the `string` package (which requires `import string`), so any string by default will be interpretted as `str`. So I think this goes back to either the difference between how the `str` class function vs. instantiated object method acts, or as another answer I just saw states this is how the Pandas implementation treats it. I am not using `string` at all.

Comment: `'105.35'` is a string. No one said you need to import string.

Comment: I edited my question to display the difference between the `str.count('105.35', '.')` (not pandas) vs. calling the method from the `str` `105.35` (which is the instantiated `str`). It's late and I was interpretting that comment as the `string` from `import string`. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because Pandas.Series.str.count and string count methods are different.
You can see here ( https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html#pandas.Series.str.count ) that Pandas.Series.str.count takes regex as argument. And “.” regex means “any symbol”, while str.count gets count of provided substrings (not regex)

Answer (score 0):

If check [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) it working with regex pattern by default, so is necessary escape `\.` for count `.` else it count all values by regex `.`'.

If want check how is implemented function in pandas check [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.3/pandas/core/strings.py#L148).

---

[`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=zfill#str.count) in pure python working different, not with regex but substring, so output different.